# MySQL saving issue node

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I’m setting up a subdomain where users can upload updates to the database.

The correct data gets sent from the front end, and the API connects to the database successfully but stops there. I can’t figure out why.

```
app.post('/newsupdate', (req, res) => {
    let headline = req.body.headline;
    let content = req.body.content;

    let con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: HOST,
        user: USERNAME,
        password: PASSWORD,
        database: DATABASE
    });

    con.connect(function(err){
        if(err) return res.json({
            message: err
        });
  
        let sql = `INSERT INTO news (Headline, Content) VALUES (${headline}, &{content})`;
  
        con.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if(err) return res.json({message: err});

            if(result){
                res.json({
                    message: 'news update saved'
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    message: 'problems happened'
                });
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: For future reference, you *probably* shouldn't put your *real* username and password into an online forum.

Comment: And you should *immediately* change your username and password because people can see the edit history on your question.

Comment: Also, looking at your code, I'd suggest looking into prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your query (`&{content}`), try to use a prepared statement as suggested:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO news (Headline, Content) VALUES (?, ?)`;

con.query(sql, [headline, content], function (err, result) {
  if (err) return res.json({ message: err });

  if (result) {
    res.json({
      message: 'news update saved',
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      message: 'problems happened',
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I refactored to this and it still isn’t actually saving anything to the db, and my res.json isn’t working either. All my other routes in this api work fine though?

Comment: Addendum: the con.query function is getting called, cuz it’s console.logging “saved” and shit from within the callback, it just isn’t actually functioning

Comment: @MixedByInstinct Can you post the result of `console.log(req.body)` and the structure of the `news` table?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev on further inspection, it’s saving to the db just fine. res.json isn’t working but my original question has been answered lol. Thanks everyone 

Comment: Final update: I was missing an e.preventDefault() call in my frontend so the page was refreshing instead of displaying the response where I wanted. It’s been a long week lol

Answer (score 0):

your syntax typo, just change to

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO news (Headline, Content) VALUES (${headline}, ${content})`;
```